# Getting WebBrowser Control To Work In Console Application?

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, console-application

I have a printer class that is capable of printing HTML via the WebBrowser object.  I want to be able to print from a console application, but I get an error when my printer class tries to create a WebBrowser object:

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
```

Error:

```
ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot 
be instantiated because the current thread is not in a 
single-threaded apartment.
```

I tried adding a reference to System.Windows.Forms into my console application but that didn't work.  I don't have the slightest idea of what's going on here, but I would appreciate the help.

Comment: If still interested, have a loop at [this implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19718530/1768303).

Answer (score 22):

Add STAThread attribute to your main method.

```
[STAThread]
public static Main()
{
    ...
}
```

**Update:** Here what you should do with thread where Browser is created

```
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
```

**Update 2:**

If one thread per app:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
```

Comment: My program runs with [STAThread], but it doesn't actually print.

Comment: I have a brand new console application that calls the print method from my print class in the Main method.  I don't think I'm creating any other threads in my console application. Please let me know if that doesn't answer your question thanks.

Comment: I don't understand how you would set "therad" to the current thread?  My WebBrowser opens just from the main printer class.  I really appreciate the help so far :)

Answer (score 10):

A console mode app and WebBrowser are water and fire.  You need to follow the single-threaded apartment contract for a thread to use WebBrowser:

- must be an STA, use [STAThread] on Main() or Thread.SetApartmentState() if you create a thread.
- must pump a message loop, Application.Run() available in Winforms or WPF.

The second requirement is a hard one for WebBrowser, it won't fire its events if you don't use it.  Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269800/c-webbrowser-control-in-a-new-thread/4271581#4271581) for the code to create a thread that runs WB.  A GUI app based on Winforms or WPF will always have its main thread already suitable to use WB.

Comment: Thank you for the `Thread.SetApartmentState()` tip, in SSIS I can't use `[STAThread]` and I spent a lot of time looking for an alternative!